# folium.Choropleth: control fill_opacity for null values only

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, alpha, folium

I have drawn a nice map of the US.
I have made `Choropleth` using `Folium`

```
folium.Choropleth(
 geo_data=boundaries,
 name='choropleth',
 data=df,
 columns=['state','NR'],
 key_on='feature.id',
 fill_color='Blues',
 threshold_scale=a_non_unform_log_scale,
fill_opacity=0.7
).add_to(m)
```

[image]

It is exaclty as I wanted, but I would like to give the value 0 a special transparent color.
E.g. in the image many states are black because they had a null/nan entry in `df`.
Can I make just transparent the missing states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can do the following:

```
folium.Choropleth(
 geo_data=boundaries,
 name='choropleth',
 data=df,
 columns=['state','NR'],
 nan_fill_color='grey',
 nan_fill_opacity=0.4,
 key_on='feature.id',
 fill_color='Blues',
 threshold_scale=a_non_unform_log_scale,
fill_opacity=0.7
).add_to(m)
```